# Spring Security authenticationFailure

Tags: spring, spring-security, zk

i am using Spring Security for identification  but when I try to identify with the right username and password it did not working i get `authentication-failure-url="/login.zul?error=true"`, i am using a password encoder ,i encode the password before to persist it in database using the  `BCryptPasswordEncoder` offered by Spring Security,i noticed that while authentication process ,the class `CustomUserDetailsService` it never executed .

this is my configuration :

```
    <form-login login-page="/login.zul" default-target-url="/index.zul"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.zul?error=true"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/profil.zul" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*.zul" access="isAnonymous()" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/index.zul" />
</http>


<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"
    id="passwordEncoder" />

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
    class="ma.csimaroc.core.profil.services.impl.CustomUserDetailsService"
    autowire="byName" />

<beans:bean id="authProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="authProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

MyUserDetailService :

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    UserDao userDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserDetails user = null;

        UserBD userBean = userDao.getUserByName(username);

        System.out.println(userBean.getUsername());

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userBean.getUserRole()
                .getRole()));

        user = new User(userBean.getUsername(), userBean.getPassword()
                .toLowerCase(), true, true, true, true, authList);

        return user;
    }

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
 }
```

My web.xml :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                     /WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: i already mentioned the declaration of passwordEncoder in my XML configuration? how to activate Spring logger ?

Comment: i debugged i found this message error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread ,the Session is declared in applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 1):

Having tried to replicate issue on my own system i had the problem with the below setup:

UserDao userDao; in your CustomUserDetailsService  function.

change it to:

```
@Autowired
private USerDao userDao;
```

If that doesn't work, please let me know and i'll investigate further for you.

Comment: no the problem is not there because if was so it will give me a NullPointerException but the problem it's redirect me as if i entered a wrong passaword and username

Comment: I know its a silly question but have you tried to see how it behaves if you did implement it?

Comment: yes i added @Autowired ,and it give the same result

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, let me review your code again and i'll get back to you. Could you please paste in code how you hashing/encoding the user's password when you persist the user into the database initially?

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug, and to put a breakpoint in Spring' UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. It will be easy to see what is the failure reason.

Comment: but how to do so i am not implementing UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter ?

Comment: even though you are not implementing this class, you can still debug it. You have the source because Spring is open-source (you can download the source manually in case your IDE does not do so automatically)

Comment: i just found what is the problem i did not the soluton yet